# Facebook API OAuth Excpetion #200 with '&scope=publish_steam'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to post a status update using facebook php sdk.  Code posted below.  As I understand it, I need ask for extended persmission, which I do in the login URL with '&scope=publish_stream', but this still isn't working.

The resultant login URL looks like:
    https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=174954539217971&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2facebook.post.php&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffacebook.post.php&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&scope=publish_stream

So you can see it is being set.  While this is essentially the same question as: [Facebook OAuthException: "user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158164/facebook-api-oauthexception-200)

The suggested solution in that thread is not working here.

```
<?php

echo "Posting to facebook..<br/>";

require './fb_src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'appId',
  'secret' => 'secret',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream')));
    error_log($e);
  }
}
else {
  header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream')));
}

print_r($me);

try {
  $feed = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message' => 'Hello world!', 'cb' => ''));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  print($e);
}
print_r($feed);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter is 'req_perms' not 'scope'.  So hard to find good documentation...

Works fine now.

Comment: you sure? req_perms is not working anymore since yesterday, i changed to scope and its working again... wtf?